# Springboot application problem running on spring suite tool

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

Web server failed to start. Port 8080 was already in use.

Action:

Identify and stop the process that's listening on port 8080 or configure this application to listen on another port.

i tried using commands still nit working...

Comment: in your application.properties file try setting server.port=8081 and then run the application

Comment: hi & welcome: [win](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48198/592355)|[x-like](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/106561/112506) ..with that information you should be able to "kill"/resolve it ;)